# having the hardest time passing NULL to my database

Tags: php, mysql, null

im working on a part of program where i need to send null to my database if the textbox is empty here is what i have so far

```
<?php
//so if not connected to database it displays an error message instead of a php error recommend having on 1 in development mode - for warnings and error
ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
if(!$_POST) exit;

        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","imstillr","password");
        mysql_select_db("imstillr_crm", $con);  


        $company = protect($_POST['company']); //required
        $primarycontact = protect($_POST['primarycontact']); //required
        $primaryemail   = protect($_POST['primaryemail']); //required
        $preferphone = protect($_POST['preferphone']); //required
        $secondarycontact = protect($_POST['secondarycontact']);
        $secondaryemail = protect($_POST['secondaryemail']);
        $optionalphone = protect($_POST['optionalphone']);
        $department = protect($_POST['department']);
        $website = protect($_POST['website']); //required*/

        //database info

        mysql_query("SELECT companyname FROM customerinfo WHERE companyname='" .$company. "'");

        if (!$con)
        {
            //checks if database connection string is correct
            echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! no database connection.</div>';
            exit(); 
        } else if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
            echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! This company already exists.</div>';        
            exit(); 
        } else if(trim($company) == '') {
            echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your company name.</div>';
            exit();
        } else if(trim($primarycontact) == '') {
            echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter a contact name.</div>';
            exit();
        } else if(trim($primaryemail) == '') {
            echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
            exit();
        } else if(!isEmail($primaryemail)) {
            echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have to enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
            exit();
        } else if(trim($department) == '') {
            echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a department.</div>';
            exit();
        } else if(trim($preferphone) == '') {
            echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a preferred phone number.</div>';
            exit();
        } else if(!isPhone($preferphone)) {
            echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter the right format for phone.</div>';
            exit();
        } else if(trim($website) == '') {
            echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a website name.</div>';
            exit();
        }

        if($error == '') {

        $secondarycontact = NULL;
        $secondaryemail = 'random text';
        $optionalphone = 'random text';


         $address = "example@yahoo.com";
         $clientaddress = $primaryemail;

        //admin subject
         $e_subject = $primarycontact .' has successfully been registered in the database';

         //client subject
         $c_subject = 'You have successfully been registered in the database';

        /* another way of doing admin client email as array
        $admin_email = array(   
                'e_body' => '$primarycontact has been registered in department '$department' \r\n\n',
                'e_content' => 'You have been contacted by $name with regards to $subject, their additional message is as follows.\r\n\n';
                'e_reply' => 'You can contact $primarycontact via email, $primaryemail';
        );*/

        //admin email
         $e_body = "$primarycontact has been registered in department '$department' \r\n\n";
         //$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to $subject, their additional message is as follows.\r\n\n";
         $e_content = "Company Name: $company\n Primary Contact: $primarycontact\n Primary Email: $primaryemail\n Preferred Phone: $preferphone\n Secondary Contact: $secondarycontact\n Secondary Email: $secondaryemail\n Optional Phone: $optionalphone\n Department: $department\n Website: $website \r\n\n";
        //$e_content = "\"anything can be displayed here such as all the customers entered info\"\r\n\n";
         $e_reply = "You can contact $primarycontact via email, $primaryemail ";

         //client email
        $c_body = "You has been registered in department '$department' \r\n\n";
        $c_content = "Company Name: $company\n Primary Contact: $primarycontact\n Primary Email: $primaryemail\n Preferred Phone: $preferphone\n Secondary Contact: $secondarycontact\n Secondary Email: $secondaryemail\n Optional Phone: $optionalphone\n Department: $department\n Website: $website \r\n\n";
        $c_reply = "For anymore information feel free to contact the administrator vis email, $address";


        //admin msg                 
        $msg = $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply;
        //client msg
        $cmsg = $c_body . $c_content . $c_reply;

         //inserts information


         mysql_query("INSERT INTO `imstillr_crm`.`customerinfo` (`id`, `companyname`, `primarycontact`, `primaryemail`, `prefphone`, `secondarycontact`, `secondaryemail`, `optionalphone`, `department`, `website`) VALUES (NULL, '".$company."', '".$primarycontact."', '".$primaryemail."', '".$preferphone."', '".$secondarycontact."', '".$secondaryemail."', '".$optionalphone."', '".$department."', '".$website."')");
         if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, "From: $primaryemail\r\nReply-To: $primaryemail\r\nReturn-Path: $primaryemail\r\n")) {

        //if mail was sent to admin then send to person who signed up
        mail($primaryemail, $c_subject, $cmsg, "From: $address\r\nReply-To: $address\r\nReturn-Path: $address\r\n");
         // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.


         echo "<fieldset>";         
         echo "<div id='success_page'>";
                   echo $secondarycontact. '<br />';
        echo $secondaryemail. '<br />';
        echo $optionalphone. '<br />';

         //echo "<h1>User $primarycontact Successfully added onto '$department'.</h1>";
         echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$primarycontact</strong>, your registration info has been submitted to us.</p>";
         echo "</div>";
         echo "</fieldset>";

        } else {

         echo 'ERROR!';

        }

    }
//all functions go here

//protects database from SQL injection
function protect($value) {
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        return mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($value));
    }else{
        return mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
}
function isEmail($email) { // Email address verification, do not edit.

return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));

}
function isPhone($number) { 

return(preg_match("/^([\(]{1}[0-9]{3}[\)]{1}[ ]{1}[0-9]{3}[\-]{1}[0-9]{4})$/",$number));

}
?>
```

optionalphone,secondaryemail and secondarycontact are the only values that can be null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not work:

```
$foo = null;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ... VALUES (".$foo.")");
```

This will:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ... VALUES (NULL)");
```

So you might want to do it this way:

```
function quoted_string_or_null($var) {
    return $var === null ? 'NULL' : "'".$var."'";
}

$foo = null;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ... VALUES (".quoted_string_or_null($foo).")");
```

However, there is another problem: there is no way you will be getting real `null` values from your `protect` function or from $_POST. So you have to decide if an empty string is a legal value, or if empty strings should be converted to `null`. It's probably the latter, so you can make a small change and work with this:

```
function quoted_string_or_null($var) {
    return ($var === null || $var === '') ? 'NULL' : "'".$var."'";
}
```

Comment: can you explain what ":" is im guess its else? and what does "?" where can i find information about writing inline if statements?

Comment: @josh: It's called the *ternary operator*: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 1):

Rather than manually quoting the strings, use something to do this for you.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

In the comments is a function written for your issue:

```
<?php
function db_escape($values, $quotes = true) {
    if (is_array($values)) {
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $values[$key] = db_escape($value, $quotes);
        }
    }
    else if ($values === null) {
        $values = 'NULL';
    }
    else if (is_bool($values)) {
        $values = $values ? 1 : 0;
    }
    else if (!is_numeric($values)) {
        $values = mysql_real_escape_string($values);
        if ($quotes) {
            $values = '"' . $values . '"';
        }
    }
    return $values;
}
?>
```

Once you have escaped each value, pass it without any extra quotes to the insert command.